# Android assetManager getAsset() throwing nullPointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have 2 classes, from class BinderData, which extends BaseAdapter (I can't extend this class to Activity as I have to extend to BaseAdapter) I am calling class AssetActivity by following code:

```
AssetActivity a = new AssetActivity();
Drawable image=a.getImage(imageUri);
```

Here imageuri is a string and it is populated properly.In the AssetActivity class following code I am using.

```
public class AssetActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "AssetActivity";

    public Drawable getImage(String imgName) {

        String nextImageName = imgName+ ".jpg";
        AssetManager assets = getAssets(); // get app's AssetManager
        InputStream stream; // used to read in Image images     
        Drawable flag=null;
        try {
            // get an InputStream to the asset representing the next Image
            stream = assets.open(nextImageName );

            // load the asset as a Drawable and display on the objImageView
             flag = Drawable.createFromStream(stream, nextImageName);
        } // end try
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error loading " + nextImageName, e);
        } // end catch
        return flag;
    }
}
```

When I am running the code I am getting NullPointerException at following line.

```
AssetManager assets = getAssets();
```

There are assets at the asset folder and I am able to fetch them in some other class which explicitly calls getAssets() method and that class extends Activity. Please help me with this. I am suspecting that I am doing something wrong in calling getImage method in BinderData class. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AssetManager assets = getAssets();` will give you `NullPointerException` because `getAssets()` will return `null`. `getAssets()` needs to be called in the Activity `Context`;

You are not allowed to create Object for the class android will take care of that through life cycle methods. So don't create Object for Activity.

place that method in your Activity class use `context.getAssets()` to get the Assets

Comment: Thnx but can u please elaborate more as I am new to Android and Java.

Comment: @Sid ok..What else do you want to know? Simply place that method in your current Activity it self and call it directly. use `context.getAssets()` in place of `getAssets()`

Comment: I can't place the method in my main class as it's not an activity it's a BaseAdapter. I didn't understand context.getAssets() and how to use it. Shall I use it in Activity class?

Comment: if it is based Adapter, you'll need supply context in the constructor of your CustomAdapter. And using that context you can get the assets

Comment: ok I tried what you said. But still I m getting same error.    private static Context appContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {    super.onCreate();
         appContext = this;
    }
    public static Context getContext()
    {
         return appContext;
    } then I am using AssetManager assets = appContext.getAssets();

Comment: I made this class as Application instead of Activity but of no use.

Comment: @Sid Please use method in the same class i.e in the same Activity instead of Making other class Activity or Application and calling the method. If you want to use outside you need to pass `Context` as arugment to the Constructor of the other class and use that `context` to get Assets