# Access assets in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-assets, android-typeface

I have a Font in my assets folder and I called it in my fragment like this:

```
Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/myFont.otf");
```

But I got a lint warning saying that `getAssets()` may return null.

I did some research and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16571740/5550161) question/answer. I'm currently already getting the activities context.

---

What I was thinking of doing is adding the following method in my `Activity`:

```
public static Typeface getMyFont(Activity context){
    return Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),  "fonts/myFont.otf");
}
```

and then calling it from my fragment like this:

```
mTextView.setTypeface(Activity.getMyFont(getActivity()));
```

---

By doing the above I don't get any warnings, but I'm not sure if it is the correct way, so..

**My Question is:**
Should I ignore the lint warning? Should I do it like I done above or is there a correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I got a lint warning saying that getAssets() may return null.

in `Fragments` `getActivity()` can return `null` if the fragment is not currently attached to a parent activity,

**Solution 1 :** check that your activity in not null

```
 if(getActivity()!=null){
            Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/myFont.otf");
 }
```

**Solution 2 :** you can use **`onAttach()`** to get context

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {


    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        mContext=context;
    }

    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/myFont.otf");

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    }

}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer. So, would a work-around be to check if `getActivity` is null, like - `if (getActivity() != null)`?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use from below code:

```
Typeface myFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "myFont.ttf");
mTextView.setTypeface(myFont)
```

it worked successfully.

Comment: If you read my question you will see that this is what I have done. That is why I'm asking the question in the first place.