# getContext() doesn't return null when fragment not attached?

Tags: android, android-fragments

An async task in a `Fragment` used to crash my app if the app was suddenly closed. The post execute code ran (e.g. show a `Toast`), but there was no app anymore.

I thought I fixed this by checking `getContext() != null` before running post execute code, but I got another crash.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException:
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.requireContext (Fragment.java:614)
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources (Fragment.java:678)
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getString (Fragment.java:700)
  at com.grammarbud.android.grammarbud.MainFragment$2.onBillingServiceDisconnected (MainFragment.java:310)
```

I read that

> Fragments now have requireContext(), requireActivity(), requireHost(), and requireFragmentManager() methods, which return a NonNull object of the equivalent get methods or throw an IllegalStateException.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#27-1-0

Does this mean `getContext()` doesn't return `null` anymore? But then what does the below excerpt mean? Will it return `null` or not when not attached to the `Activity`? I don't understand the language.

> The getActivity and getContext methods return nullable types because when the Fragment is not attached to an Activity, these methods already returned null. There's no change in behaviour, it's just explicitly marked now, so you can safely handle it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47253335/3268303

My code, which is run in a Fragment

```
private void connectToPlayStore() {
    mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBillingSetupFinished(@BillingClient.BillingResponse int billingResponseCode) {
            if (billingResponseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                if (getContext() != null) {
                    queryProductDetails();
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            // Line below ***CRASHES*** app if closed prematurely
                SharedHelper.showToast(getContext(), getString(R.string.no_connection_to_play_store));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The `SharedHelper` function to show the Toast, which would catch if context is `null`, but execution doesn't get this far it seems to me

```
public static void showToast(Context context, String message) {
    if (context != null) {
        Toast newToast = Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        showToast(newToast);
    }
}
```

So how to properly provide for the scenario when an async task is running in a fragment and the app is suddenly closed? Should I try to end connection with `BillingClient.endConnection()`? Will this guarantee that post execute code is not run? It doesn't explicitly say in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.html#endconnection).

Also someone mentioned `isAdded()`. Should I check `isAdded()` instead of `getActivity() != null && getContext() != null`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51357755/7666442

Comment: *getContext() doesn't return null when fragment not attached?* ... why you are thinking so? OBVIOUSLY the problem is not `getContext()`  but `getString(..)`

Comment: You're absolutely right!! The problem is `getString()`. For some reason I assumed `getContext()` was the problem, but this is wrong. Thanks so much for pointing it out!!! Wouldn't have realised on my own I was so focused on `getContext()`